# Magento 2: Date in email template

Tags: magento2, php

How can I add a custom variable to a email template in Magento 2 ?

I know that I can generate custom variables with HTML output but I want to output some PHP code.

I want to echo the date of the order in the email.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Example of the email header]

**EDIT:**
Please note that I'm editing the email template in the admin section of the website. Not directly in the PHTML file.

Comment: Use `{{trans "%orderDate" orderDate=$data.orderDate}}` in ur mail template & pass orderDate variable from PHP

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @AnkitShah Where do I set the function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{trans "%orderDate" orderDate=$data.orderDate}}` in ur mail template & in PHP

```
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTempVariables['orderDate'] = <order id from DB>;

$postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$postObject->setData($emailTempVariables);
```

Comment: Thank you @AnkitShah for your reply!, In which file do I need to put this in?

Please note that I'm editing the email template in the admin section of the website. Not directly in the PHTML file.